# Update value in a row if value in another row is equal to a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [0, 1, 2],
                   'values1': ['name', 'a', 'x'],
                   'values2': ['PST', 'b', 'y'],
                   'values3': ['noPST', 'c', 'z'],
                   'values4': ['noPST', 'd', 'h'],
                   'values5': ['PST', 'e', 'j']})
```

```
index values1 values2 values3 values4   values5
  0    name      PST     noPST    noPST    PST
  1    a         b        c       d        e
  2     x        y        z       h        j
```

How can I replace all values in row indexed 2 to `v`  if the value in the first row (indexed 0) is equal to `PST`.

As a result I would like to get:

```
index values1 values2 values3 values4   values5
  0    name      PST     noPST    noPST    PST
  1    a         b        c       d        e
  2     x        v        z       h        v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index the columns with a boolean Series and then use `loc`:

```
relevant_cols = df.columns[df.loc[0]=='PST']
df.loc[2, relevant_cols] = 'v'
```

Output:

```
   index values1 values2 values3 values4 values5
0      0    name     PST   noPST   noPST     PST
1      1       a       b       c       d       e
2      2       x       v       z       h       v
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit similar to enke answer but a bit more straight forward as extracting column names is not essential, can be done for self explanatory code !!works!!

```
df.loc[2,df.loc[0]=='PST']='V'
```

output:

```
   index values1 values2 values3 values4 values5
0      0    name     PST   noPST   noPST     PST
1      1       a       b       c       d       e
2      2       x       V       z       h       V
```

Comment: Nice! (+1) I had this initially but figured it may be more understandable if columns were selected explicitly. But yeah in terms of performance, this is better.